# Django: set_password isn't hashing passwords?

Tags: python, django, hash, django-forms, django-views

I've made a custom User registration form/view in Django so that I can include an additional user attributes through a different model. I've used set_password to set the password of the newly created user to the password entered in the form, but I've found that the passwords that are saved aren't hashed.

form:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('username', 'email', 'password')


class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ('theclass',)
        widgets = {
            'theclass': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
        }

class TeacherForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Teacher
        fields = ('theclass',)
        widgets = {
        'theclass': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
        }
```

view:

```
def register_student(request):
context = RequestContext(request)
registered = False
if request.method == 'POST':
    user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST)
    student_form = StudentForm(data = request.POST)

    if user_form.is_valid() and student_form.is_valid():
        user = user_form.save()
        user.set_password(user.password)

        user.save

        student = student_form.save(commit = False)
        student.user = user
        student.save()
        registered = True
else:
    user_form = UserForm()
    student_form = StudentForm()
return render_to_response('classapp/register_student.html', {'user_form': user_form, 'student_form': student_form, 'registered': registered}, context)

def register_teacher(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    registered = False
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST)
        teacher_form = TeacherForm(data = request.POST)
    if user_form.is_valid() and teacher_form.is_valid():

        user = user_form.save()

        user.set_password(user.password)

        user.save

        teacher = teacher_form.save(commit = False)
        teacher.user = user
        teacher.save()
        registered = True
else:
    user_form = UserForm()
    teacher_form = TeacherForm()
return render_to_response('classapp/register_teacher.html', {'user_form': user_form, 'teacher_form': teacher_form, 'registered': registered}, context)
```

When I register a user through this form, the login is invalid. I checked the user information on Admin, and found that the password field said:
*Invalid password format or unknown hashing algorithm.*
I also synced the db and opened the shell and manually retrieved the user objects that were created using my registration form and found that the user password is not being hashed, like so:

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> user = User.objects.get(username = "username")
>>> user.password
u'password'
>>> user = User.objects.get(username = "superuser")
>>> user.password
u****hashed password****
```

Users created using Admin have their passwords hashed, but my custom form does not.The documentation says that set_password(raw_password) takes care of hashing automatically.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`set_password` only creates a hashed password; it doesn't save the value in the database. Call `save()` to actually save it.

---

In your views, it should be

```
user.save()
```

below the line

```
user.set_password(user.password)
```

You didn't write the brackets (parentheses). That's why `save` method is not being called after you hash the password.

Comment: From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.set_password):  
set_password(raw_password).
Sets the user’s password to the given raw string, taking care of the password hashing. Doesn’t save the User object.

Comment: what the difference between `set_password` and `make_password`
`user.set_password(password)`
vs
`user.password = make_password(password)`

Comment: @AzharUddinSheikh There's a small difference. Check the source code: https://github.com/django/django/blob/4.2.4/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py#L107-L109. The `set_password` method also saves a reference to the new raw password. This is used later while saving the user as explained on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58265752/1925257

Answer (score 6):

```
user.set_password(user.password)
user.save()
```

Answer (score 2):

**answer update 25 july 2021**

set_password method working django version 3.2

#### custom singup django 3.2

make sure the variable not passing null. for development you can make print before pass to set_password method.

```
def user_register(request):

  if (request.method == 'POST'):
        username = request.POST.get('username')
      
        password = request.POST.get('password')
  print(password, type(password))
  #make sure the password not passed null
  user = User.objects.create_user(
            email=email,
            name=username,  
            password=password,
        )      
  user.set_password(password)
  user.save()
```

how you test with django shell.

```
python manage.py shell
```

#### here list django shell commands

```
from .models import user_type, User

user = User.objects.create_user(email="ll55@gmail.com",password="uU123456",name="le5")
user.set_password("uU123456")
user.save()



u = User.objects.get(name="as6")
u.name
u.password
```

Comment: I just wanted to highlight here is, Django doesn’t support `name` & if you try to pass it to constructor like `User(name='Rishikesh')` this then you will observe `TypeError: User() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'` exception.

Comment: `user.set_password(password)` this line is required inorder to store **hashed passwords** thanks Mr Coder