# Django User model: what is the purpose of password changes in the save() method

Tags: django, django-authentication

Sometimes i want to set the password programmatically. I do the following:

```
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#changing-passwords
You can also change a password programmatically, using set_password():

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
u = User.objects.get(username='john')
u.set_password('new pass')
u.save()
```

I wanted to see how things are implemented in save() when we run `u.save()`

Basically I am trying to understand the save() method used in AbstractBaseUser

```
# ./.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py
class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
    password = models.CharField(_('password'), max_length=128)

    ........

    # Stores the raw password if set_password() is called so that it can
    # be passed to password_changed() after the model is saved.
    _password = None


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        if self._password is not None:
            password_validation.password_changed(self._password, self)
            self._password = None

    ........

    def set_password(self, raw_password):
        self.password = make_password(raw_password)
        self._password = raw_password
```

Here in `def save(self, *args, **kwargs):`

```
super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

will save the password set by set_password before the next lines `password_validation.password_changed` which validate the password

So what is the point in saving the password first and then validating afterwards, because it's already gone into the database.

Answer (score 5):

`password_validation.password_changed` does not do what you think it does.

The actual password validation is done before the User object is saved, by calling the `django.contrib.auth.password_validation.validate_password` method. 
This method calls every validator in your settings `AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS`, and raises an exception when any of these validators fail. This can be any kind of validation, like whether the new password is complex enough, or whether it is different enough from the username.

According to [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/passwords/):

> By default, validators are used in the forms to reset or change
>   passwords and in the createsuperuser and changepassword management
>   commands.
>
> Validators aren’t applied at the model level, for example in
>   User.objects.create_user() and create_superuser(), because we assume
>   that developers, not users, interact with Django at that level and
>   also because model validation doesn’t automatically run as part of
>   creating models.

So, the User save model doesn't do any validation on the User's password, the Forms and commands do. If you manually set the password in the code somewhere, make sure you do that validation yourself.

**So what does `password_validation.password_changed(self._password, self)` do?**

Simply said, it informs all active validators that the user has changed their password, along with the actual *raw* new password. Why is this necessary? Suppose I write a validator that checks whether a user tries to change their password to a password they have used before. This validator will need to know which passwords the user has had in the past, so I'll need to save a list of (hashed) original passwords per user.

`password_changed` is basically a way for Django to say to all password validators: *"Hey, take note, the user's password has been changed to this value, so if you need to keep track of for some reason, do it now, because after this, I'll destroy the unhashed version of this password"*

Comment: `The actual password validation is done before the User object is saved, by calling the django.contrib.auth.password_validation.validate_password method. ` Can you tell where it mentioned i mean which class

Comment: `password_changed -  is basically a way for Django to say to all password validators: "Hey, take note, the user's password has been changed to this value, ` I think this can be the only reason. I thought its again validating.

Comment: `Validators aren’t applied at the model level, for example in User.objects.create_user() and create_superuser(), because we assume that developers, not users, interact with Django at that level and also because model validation doesn’t automatically run as part of creating models.` From this its clear that there is no validation done when i save() the model directly without going through a form.

Comment: The method itself is defined in the [package I named](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/_modules/django/contrib/auth/password_validation/).

It is called in (for example) the UserCreationForm and PasswordForms in [this file](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/forms.py)

Comment: Your assertion is correct. Validation should be done before calling the object's save method

Comment: Both the links are not working for me. What i wanted to say you are giving the forms reason to a direct model saving case. I know there is password validation when we create the password but it does not validate when you use direct django commands. But you got it right and thanks for giving me the understanding about password_changed

Comment: I'm not sure about the direct Django commands, it's what the docs say, but I couldn't really find any calls to validate_password in their sources.

Comment: I am little puzzled that what is to need to inform the password validators about  password_changed . The purpose of validators is to validate. One by one they validate the password. But the reason can be that, the person who is using Django direct commands should be aware if there is an validation error in the password he set, even though he is allowed to save the password. I think its more of philosophy Django follows than the logic here. The user using direct commands should be aware of what he is doing, rather than stop him at this level, but still give him some validation errors if he want

Comment: 1) So definitely the `password_changed` is meant for validation and not meant for informing. So your anwer is not correct i feel
2) Then why the `model` is saved before `password_changed` validating is done is that "Thats the way Django wants it to be".

Comment: Nope, password_changed does not do any actual validation, it only informs validators that need to be aware of old passwords that the password has been changed.

Comment: I dont agree with this. I think validators main purpose is validating

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200503/discussion-between-nico-griffioen-and-santhosh-yedidi).