# Django - authenticate() returning None even if user exists in database and the credentials are correct

Tags: python, django, authentication

`authenticate()` returns `None` for credentials even if the user exists in the database and the credentials are correct.

The function for registration, `register()`:

```
def register(request):
    registered = False
    ctx = {}

    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get("username")
        full_name = request.POST.get("fullname")
        password = request.POST.get("password")
        email = request.POST.get("email")
        if len(User.objects.filter(username=username)) == 0:
            ctx["username_exists"] = False
            user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST)
            if user_form.is_valid():
                user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
                user.save()
                user_profile = UserProfile(user=user, full_name=full_name, email_id=email)
                user_profile.save()
                if user:
                    if user.is_active:
                        login(request,user)
                        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
                    else:
                        return HttpResponse("Your account was inactive.")
                else:
                    print("Someone tried to login and failed.")
                    print("They used username: {} and password: {}".format(username,password))
                    return HttpResponse("Invalid login details given")
            else:
                return HttpResponse("Contains @")
        else:
            ctx["username_exists"] = True
            return render(request,'main/register.html', ctx)
    elif request.method == "GET":
        form = User()
        ctx["form"] = form
        return render(request,'main/register.html', ctx)
```

Looking at the admin, I can see the user exists. The following proves it exists in the database:

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> user = User.objects.get(username='<username>')
>>> print(user)
<username>
```

This is what I'm doing -

```
python3 manage.py shell
>>> from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
>>> user = authenticate(username="<username>", password="<password>")
>>> print(user)
None
```

While trying out what @Abdulmajeed said, I found something weird:

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
>>> user = User.objects.get(username='<username>')
>>> print(user)
<username>
>>> user_authenticate = authenticate(username='<username>', password='<password>')
>>> print(user_authenticate)
None
>>> user.set_password('<password>')
>>> user.check_password('<password>')
True
>>> user_authenticate = authenticate(username='<username>', password='<password>')
>>> print(user_authenticate)
None
```

This is my `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS`:
`AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',]`

This hasn't ever occurred to me before and I don't know what to do. Help?

Comment: `set_password()` only attaches the password to the `user` instance. This is temporary. The value is not saved in the database. You've to call `user.save()` to save the hashed password ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30466918/1925257)) in the database. This is why `check_password()` is passing because the `user` variable has the password, but the `authenticate()` function fetches the user from the database which still has the old value.

Comment: That works, thanks a lot. Will you create an answer for it?

Comment: Abdulmajeed's answer is also correct. You can mark that as *accepted*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS setting in your Django settings file includes the ModelBackend backend or you can check by verify that the password for the user is correct

```
if len(User.objects.filter(username=username)) == 0:
            ctx["username_exists"] = False
            user = User.objects.create(username=username, email=email)
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()
            user_profile = UserProfile(user=user, full_name=full_name, email_id=email)
            user_profile.save()
            authenticated_user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if authenticated_user is not None:
                login(request, authenticated_user)
                return redirect(reverse('index'))
            else:
                return HttpResponse("Unable to authenticate the user.")
```

Comment: Please look at the new edit I made to the post

Comment: `check_password()` returns True but `authenticate()` returns None even if my `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` is what you told me to set it to.

Comment: Can you try to print out user_form.errors in your registration view to see if there are any validation errors?!

Comment: If the password in returning true. It has to be the issue with the user. Can you check if the user is Active or inactive ?

Comment: @Abjulmajeed I'm not using Django forms for this one because I needed specific views. `user_form` doesn't exist.

Comment: The user is active: 
` >>> print(user.is_active)`
`True`

Comment: create the User object and call the set_password() method to hash the password before saving it to the database. I have edits my answer, we can try this manually